# Send multiple values to Raspberry with Arduino using serial

Tags: python, json, arduino, raspberry-pi, pyserial

I have got a question about serial communication between Arduino and Raspberry Pi. The fact is I want to send 2 variables to Raspberry Pi with Arduino and use them in different ways.

Here my sketch for Arduino :

```
int one = 1;
int two = 2;

void setup() 
{

     Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() 
{
   Serial.print(one);
   Serial.print(two);
   delay(3000);
```

}

Here my python script for Raspberry:

```
import serial
import time

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600)
time.sleep(4)

while True:
    data=ser.read()
    print data
```

The problem is that 'data' in the python code takes the two values send by Arduino (because of two print in the Arduino loop() ). But I want to receive the datas in Raspberry Pi with two different variables (to record them after). I try many technics to receive these datas in two different ways, but it not work.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Arduino's [`Serial.print`](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Serial/Print) sends data as ASCII. 
So your commands from the Arduino actually send the string `12`.
There is no way for Python do see where the first value ends and where the second one begins.

One solution is to use [`Serial.println`](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Serial/Println) instead of `Serial.print`.
This will add a carriage return and a newline after each call.
So the string will become `1\r\n2\r\n`.

On the Python side you can then use the `split` method.
An example in IPython:

```
In [1]: recv = "1\r\n2\r\n"

In [2]: recv.split()
Out[2]: ['1', '2']
```

And you can then easily convert the values to integers.

```
In [3]: [int(j) for j in recv.split()]
Out[3]: [1, 2]
```

**Note**: it is possible for Python to get an incomplete message! So you just might receive the string `1` the first time you read and `2` during a second read! So you might want to consider formatting your data so you *know* you have received a complete message.

One option to do that is to format your data as JSON. In your example this would be `{"one": 1, "two": 2}`. In this simple calse you can check that you have received a complete message because it starts with a `{` and ends with a `}`. But you could also use Python's built-in JSON parser.

```
In [4]: data = {'one': 1, 'two': 2}

In [5]: import json

In [6]: json.dumps(data)
Out[6]: '{"two": 2, "one": 1}'

In [7]: recv2 = json.dumps(data)

In [8]: json.loads(recv2)
Out[8]: {'one': 1, 'two': 2}
```

Using the JSON parser has an advantage because it raises an exception when you try to parse an incomplete message:

```
In [10]: recv2
Out[10]: '{"two": 2, "one": 1}'

In [11]: recv3 = '{"two": 2, "on'

In [12]: json.loads(recv3)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
JSONDecodeError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-c1774b41dafa> in <module>()
----> 1 json.loads(recv3)

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/json/__init__.py in loads(s, encoding, cls, object_hook, parse_float, parse_int, parse_constant, object_pairs_hook, **kw)
    317             parse_int is None and parse_float is None and
    318             parse_constant is None and object_pairs_hook is None and not kw):
--> 319         return _default_decoder.decode(s)
    320     if cls is None:
    321         cls = JSONDecoder

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/json/decoder.py in decode(self, s, _w)
    337 
    338         """
--> 339         obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
    340         end = _w(s, end).end()
    341         if end != len(s):

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/json/decoder.py in raw_decode(self, s, idx)
    353         """
    354         try:
--> 355             obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
    356         except StopIteration as err:
    357             raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None

JSONDecodeError: Unterminated string starting at: line 1 column 12 (char 11)
```

The correct way to deal with this is to keep reading data from the serial port and appending it to a string until parsing the data doesn't fail;

```
import serial
import json
import time

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600)

buffer = ''
while True:
    buffer += ser.read()
    try:
        data = json.loads(buffer)
        print(data)
        buffer = ''
    except json.JSONDecodeError:
        time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Re,

In first I want to thank you for your answer and to make me discover Json.
So I tried your last python code and modify my Arduino code like this :

```
int one=1;
int two=2;
int three = 3;
int four = 4;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
    Serial.println("{\"one\":\"" + String(one) +
    "\", \"two\":\"" + String(two) +
    "\", \"three\":\"" + String(three) +
    "\", \"four\":\"" + String(four) +
    "\"}");
}
```

In raspberry Py when i execute the code (without a while), the console return nothing. It seems that data send juste one character.

Thanks again

Comment: Please do not post additional questions as answers. Edit your question instead. Also, the numbers in JSON don't need quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I am quite new in these applications but I accidentally found a way straightforward.

Well of course, Roland's answer already does the job perfectly. This solution can basically do-it-very-fast.

After writing these two lines below in Arduino;

```
   Serial.print(one);
   Serial.print(two);
```

Just go and read the lines in Raspberry with the same way;

```
   ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600, timeout=1)
   ser.flush()

   one = ser.readline().decode('utf-8').rstrip()
   two = ser.readline().decode('utf-8').rstrip()
```

I think the trick here putting two readline() subsequently read the lines printed by Arduino in accordance. At least it worked for me :)

Well, I am not expert, just a beginner.

Salutations,