# Python's serial.readline is not receiving my entire line

Tags: python, pyserial

I'm having a problem with a block of Python code reading in a string from an Arduino connected over USB. I understand that serial doesn't know what a string is or care. I'm using serial.readline, which from the documentation sounds like the perfect match, but my string isn't always complete. The weird problem is, the string doesn't always have the front of the string, but it always has the end of the string. I'm really lost on this and I'm sure it's just my lack of understanding about the nuances of reading serial data or how Python handles it.

In the code below, I loop through the serial interfaces until I find the one I'm looking for. I flush the input and give it a sleep for a couple seconds to make sure it has time to get a new read.

```
arduinoTemp = serial.Serial(iface, 9600, timeout=1)
arduinoTemp.flushInput()
arduinoTemp.flushOutput()
arduinoTemp.write("status\r\n".encode())
time.sleep(2)
read = arduinoTemp.readline().strip()
if read != "":
    #check the string to make sure it's what I'm expecting.
```

I'm sending the string in JSON.

I'm expecting something in line with this:

```
 {"id": "env monitor","distance": {"forward": {"num":"0","unit": "inches"}},"humidity": {"num":"0.00","unit": "%"},"temp": {"num":"0.00","unit": "fahrenheit"},"heatIndex": {"num":"0.00","unit": "fahrenheit"}}
```

I might get something back like this:

```
 ": t": "%"},"temp": {"num":"69.80","unit": "fahrenheit"},"heatIndex": {"num":"68.13","unit": "fahrenheit"}}
```

or this:

```
atIndex": {"num":"0.00","unit": "fahrenheit"}}
```

At first I thought it was the length of the string that might be causing some issues, but the cut off isn't always consistent, and since it has the end of the string, it stands to reason that it should have gotten everything before that.

I've verified that my Arduino is broadcasting correctly by interfacing with it directly and the Arduino IDE and serial monitor. This is definitely an issue with my Python code.

Comment: If you always get the end of  the line, this would tell me that readline() knows when to stop.  Thus I would try removing, or greatly reducing, the sleep(2) to let readline() start working as soon as possible.

Comment: This is where I may not understand the nuances of pyserial. I flushed the input, then wanted to wait a second to wait for the status ping to bounce back a response. I changed it to sleep one second before and one after, I'm just a bit at a loss on why i'd be cutting the beginning of the strong.

Comment: Been a while since I used pyserial, but I would suggest removing any sleeps and if needed just give a longer timeout value to Serial().  Also I would not routinely flush() the input unless you are sure you need to.  Wish I could offer more.

Answer (score 2):

In (serial) communications you should *always* expect to receive partial answers.

A usual solution in this case is to add whatever you read from the serial to a string/buffer until you can parse it successfully with `json.loads`.

```
import serial
import json
import time

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600)

buffer = ''
while True:
    buffer += ser.read()
    try:
        data = json.loads(buffer)
        print(data)
        buffer = ''
    except json.JSONDecodeError:
        time.sleep(1)
```

(From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40818169/send-multiple-values-to-raspberry-with-arduino-using-serial/40818452#40818452)).

Note that if you flush, you will lose data!

Also note that this is a somewhat simplified solution. Ideally the buffer should be reset to whatever remains after the successful parse. But as far as I know, the `json` module doesn't offer that functionality.

Comment: I have something pretty similar to this except that I'm reading a line. I'm thinking I'll have to scrap this and move to a buffer solution like you're giving me, but what has me really thrown off is that my code, while its not giving me the entire string, it's always giving me the end of the string, never the beginning.

Comment: @JohnSly Two possible causes are flushing the buffer or a buffer overrun. The size of the hardware buffer cannot be changed, but you should be able to set the size of the memory buffer in the serial driver. How to do this is OS specific.